# Choose File executes successfully but does not upload file in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, automated-tests, robotframework

I need to test file upload in which I will click upload button and window will be open where I can choose file to be uploaded. When I click open, file will be automatically uploaded in website.

This is my RF code

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element     css=[type='file']
Scroll Element Into View             css=[type='file']
Choose File                          css=[type='file']     C:\\tests\\upload\\example.png
Wait Until Page Contains             File uploaded
```

And this is html code

```
<div class="upload">
   <div><input class="uploadinput" type="file" name="file">Upload File</div>
</div>
```

When I run this code, it will fail because after Choose File, nothing is happening. What should I do to trigger the change upon choosing the file so it will automatically upload?

Is there a way not to use any other library like autoit or sikuli?

EDIT

I tried to use custom keyword in python but still did not change anything. File is not being uploaded automatically.

```
def choose_upload(self, locator, file_paths):
  sl = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
  sl.find_element(locator).send_keys(file_paths)
```

EDIT TO ADD
[UI and HTML Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STZbM.png)

Comment: It's hard to know what's happening without seeing the full page, but your code looks correct. I'd check a couple things:

1. That HTML implies that the upload is firing off in Javascript with an 'onchange' event. Can you look at chrome console and see if there are any errors.
2. Make sure there's only one file input, your CSS isn't very specific, so it could be finding another element.

Comment: @MarkPercival There is no errors in chrome console. And yes, there is only one file input in the page. How will I know if the onchange event is fired? Sorry if it is dumb question. I am new on this.

Comment: dd the buttons html

Comment: @PDHide What do you mean dd?

Comment: Add the html of button and screen shot of the UI so that we can better understanding

Comment: @PDHide added the screenshot of UI and html

Comment: Is it a public websit where we can try it out ?

Comment: @PDHide it is not a public website

Answer (score 0):

> I need to test file upload in which I will click upload button

You should not click the button to activate the operating system file browser.

You mentioned click the button, although your code does not show that action.

Comment: What I mentioned clicking the button is what I do manually. Click the upload button then choose file in the pop up window.

Comment: you can use sendKeys() to send the file path to the <input type="file"> element.  Then submit() form.

Comment: @pcalkins I do not have submit() form because after choosing file, it should automatically uploaded triggered by onchange

Comment: Selenium has a .submit() method you can use on any form element to submit the form.

Comment: i also don't have form.

Comment: you'll either need a java robot, or execute a script to trigger onchange event yourself. (after using send keys on the input type='file' element.)

Answer (score 0):

You should you should see the Javascript session and see what will cause the submit event :

eg code:

I added a example code, replace the choose file with a img in your directory and run it you can see that it works as expected. Now if you check the script session we can see the #fileinput element has a even on(change) that triggers the submit action for this page. Similarly find what triggers the submit action in your case.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Robot Framework Example
Library             SeleniumLibrary
Library             BuiltIn
Library             OperatingSystem
Suite Teardown      Close Browser

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
My Testq
    Open Browser    https://codepen.io/jhoel18/pen/yyLeWv
    Select Frame    css=#result 
    ${a}=     Get Webelement     css=#filesToUpload
    Choose File    css= #filesToUpload    C:\\Users\\prave\\Downloads\\travelBA\\selenium-screenshot-1.png 
    Sleep    100000
```

Comment: Can you guide me on how to trigger the click event? Because there is not button to click to submit.

Comment: could you add screen shot of the page and the html , its hard to tell somethign without this two

Comment: i added a example ssee if it helps